# Object not getting any lights from HDRI

Tags: lighting, hdri

Im using Blender 3.3.1 and the HDRI doesnt seem to illuminate my object, not in viewport neither in render.

Im usig an .hdr for Enviroment Texture, all nodes al well connected.
Im not checking "transparent" in film.
I've check on Scene Lights and Scene World.

Does anyone know what It ma be happening?

Comment: could you please pack your image and share your file (only keep one object in your scene)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your node setup and your viewport